# Use filtered database reference in RecyclerviewAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been switching the database of my android app from realm to Firebase.
Is is possible to filter a database reference and then use it within the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Here some example:

```
DatabaseReference adapterRef = someReference.orderByChild("country").equalTo("Test").getRef();
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, adapterRef);
```

Within my recycler view all the data are shown, which means that the filtering is not working. On the other hand when I do the following:

```
someReference.orderByChild("country").equalTo("test").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Value"+snapshot);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
```

I can clearly see that the filtering is working and only items with country equals to "Test" are displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're building a query, then ignoring the query you built here:

```
DatabaseReference adapterRef = someReference
    .orderByChild("country").equalTo("Test") // here you have a query
    .getRef(); // here you get back the same location as someReference
```

The proper incantation is to pass the query in to the adapter:

```
Query query = someReference.orderByChild("country").equalTo("Test");
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, query);
```

You might need to change your `MyAdapter` constructor to allow a `Query` instead of a `DatabaseReference` to get this to compile.

Comment: Hi Frank. I am using the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and it does expect a `DatabaseReference`.

Comment: The one I wrote also accepts a query. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java#L127. If you're using another adapter as your base, please provide a link to that.

Comment: Hi Frank. Great answer. DatabaseReference is indeed a subclass of Query. I didn't notice that in the first place.